# if..else if inside a do..end block in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I wrote a program which had `if...else if` inside a `do..end` block in Ruby. Something like this:

```
[1..100].each do |num|
    if num % 3 == 0 and num % 5 == 0 
        tf += 1
    else if num % 3 == 0 and num % 5 != 0 
        t += 1
    end
    end
end
```

My question is: why is it necessary to put three `ends` at the end? From what is shown in the [Ruby Wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Control_Structures#if-elsif-else_expression), the `if..else if` requires only one `end` and the `do..end` requires only one `end` too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `else if` opens a new block. Use `elsif` to chain if and else clauses.

Answer (score 2):

Your code should be written like this:

```
[1..100].each do |num|
    if num % 3 == 0 and num % 5 == 0 
        tf += 1
    elsif num % 3 == 0 and num % 5 != 0 
        t += 1
    end
end
```

Here's how your code should have been written with an **elsif** and not an **else if**. The other end is to close the **if** at the **else if**.

Answer (score 2):

You only need one `end` to close an `if` block (even if that `if` block contains multiple `elsif`s like in the wikibook). However in your code there are two `if` blocks: one outside and another one in the `else` part of the outer `if` block.

Long story short: if you use `elsif` instead of `else if`, you only need one `end` to close the `if`.

Also note that `[1..100].each` will yield exactly once because `[1..100]` is an array with just one single element: the range object `1..100`. You probably want `(1..100).each` instead.